# Memory leak, file in use by another process exception

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, exception, filesystemwatcher

This application seems to eat a lot of memory. Maybe I'm not managing the memory properly. Can some please figure out what code needs to be optimized. And secondly, file copying is not working properly. It sometimes throws an exception, cannot access file being used by another process, this exception is being thrown at both ends the watch folder and the destination folder where I'm copying. Let me give you a brief of what I'm trying to achieve here.

I have a system that would give me an xml file in ansi format. This file would be updated regularly maybe every 3-4mins sometimes even 10-20secs. Now I'm watching this folder, as soon as it is changed I convert it to UTF-8 and copy this to another server via sftp. This sftp folder is mapped on this same machine where the conversion is happening. So the problems I'm facing is the exception it throws, can't access the file being used by another process, after a while this get's cleared. And even the memory exception, that the system is run out of memory. It's leaking memory as well. Starts at 5k, after a few hours reaches 1.2gb of memory usage. Now I need to run 3 of these similar programs watching 3 different folders. Any clues to my problems ?

```
class Test
{
    class Class1
    {
        private static FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        public static void Main()
        {
            WatchFile();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void WatchFile()
        {
            watcher.Path = @"c:\test";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = "*.xml";
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(convert);
            watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(WatcherError);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }

        public static string CrL = "\r\n";

        private static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
        {
           string FileName = f.FullPath;
           string destinationFile = @"z:\xml\test.xml";

           Thread.Sleep(2000);
           try
           {
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
                Encoding ansi = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                string xml = File.ReadAllText(FileName, ansi);
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                File.WriteAllText(FileName, @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" + xmlDoc.ToString(), utf8);

                 if (File.Exists(destinationFile))
                     File.Delete(destinationFile);
                 File.Copy(FileName, destinationFile,true);
                 Console.WriteLine("File Copied"); // for troubleshoooting only
                 Console.Write(CrL);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }
        }

        private static void WatcherError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Exception watchException = e.GetException();
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            while (!watcher.EnableRaisingEvents)
            {
                try
                {
                    WatchFile();
                    Console.WriteLine("I'm Back!!");
                }
                catch
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: What for all this magic numbers in Thread.Sleep()?

Comment: -1 for "Please debug my application for me" 'question'

Comment: Thanks, I just asked for some clues as I'm not able to figure this out.

Comment: @abatishchev: Just to wait for a while before the file get's released by other processes to avoid the exception, yet I'm getting the file copy exceptions.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11060322/495455 if you want to see if the file is being used (locked) by another process.

Comment: The lock problem seems to have been solved, thanks to Jims code below, but the memory leak is still there. Can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Every time you get an error, you call `WatchFile()` again, which adds the `convert` and `WatcherError` methods to the `Changed` and `Error` invocation lists again. That would explain a slow memory leak. The delegate invocation lists keep growing.</del>

Because the events are raised on pool threads, it's possible for your code to be processing multiple changed events concurrently.

<del>Your error handler should just re-enable the events (i.e. `Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`) It certainly shouldn't be adding event handlers again.</del>

You also need to synchronize access in your `convert` method. You could do it with a lock, but probably a better idea would be with a `Monitor.TryEnter`, like this:

```
private static object lockObject = new Object();
private static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
    {
        // unable to get lock, return.
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood the code above and am trying this at the moment. But I can't understand 'Your error handler should just re-enable the events (i.e. Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;) It certainly shouldn't be adding event handlers again.' Can you please demonstrate this. Thank you

Comment: @user726720: I misread your error handling code. I've modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I just got confused for a while, and couldn't figure out whats wrong with my error handling, anyways. I have changed my code by adding the above technique you suggested. I'm monitoring this, and it looks good so far. I would report back if any trouble comes up.. Thank you.

Comment: It's not giving me those exceptions any more after, but the memory leak still seems persistent. It keeps on growing in the task manager. Is there more clues to my memory leak problem

Comment: @user726720: One thing in your error handler is that you're not calling `Dispose` on the watcher before you create a new one. That can cause a short-term resource problem, but I don't think it'd cause a memory leak. If you're not getting lots of errors anymore, then I don't see any way your code could be the cause of a memory leak. By the way, Task Manager is notoriously unreliable for diagnosing memory leaks. Search for [memory leak C#] here on SO for information about diagnosing memory leaks.

Comment: Yes, even by using the process explorer i can see there is a memory leak at the vm. it never drops down.. It's slow but it's leaking.